# How to define abstract method in interface with different class names?

Tags: java

I‘m quite struggling by defining an abstract method in an interface. Why? In each class, related to this interface one method called “getInstance” has to be implemented. These methods returns the actual used instance.
So how do I define the abstract method in an interface for different classes?

```
public interface MyInterface {    
      public <<here is my question>> getInstance();
}

public class Class1() implements MyInterface {

      public Class1 getInstance() {
         return this;
      }
}

public class Class2() implements MyInterface {  

     public Class2 getInstance() {
        return this;
     }
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `getInstance`? Anything that can call it already has what it returns (a reference to the instance). Usually, a method called `getInstance` is `static` and not represented by an interface.

Comment: When a class implements an interface then you can substitute that class with that interface. In your case, you can write `public MyInterface getInstance(){...}`. On the run time, you check what instance do you get if you want to check if the instance if of `class1` or `class2`

Comment: Perhaps you need default method? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html

Comment: Objects of Class1 and Class2 are of type MyInterface as both the classes implement the imterface `MyInterface`. Keep the return type of `getInstance()` as `MyImterface`. Also what is the need of returning Actual class , if possible refactor the code to return type as `MyInterface`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54674628/how-to-define-abstract-method-in-interface-with-different-class-names#comment96138810_54674628), it seems unlikely you really want to do this.

You can do what [Khan Saab pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54674628/how-to-define-abstract-method-in-interface-with-different-class-names#comment96138862_54674628): Have `getInstance`'s return type be `MyInterface`. But that won't work if you need to access features of `Class1` or `Class2` that aren't part of the interface.

You can do something like this with generics:

```
public interface MyInterface<T> {    
      public T getInstance();
}

public class Class1 implements MyInterface<Class1> {
      public Class1 getInstance() {
         return this;
      }
}

public class Class2 implements MyInterface<Class2> {  
     public Class2 getInstance() {
        return this;
     }
}
```

But you couldn't (for instance) have an array of `MyInterface` and use a mix of `Class1` and `Class2` in it (without `instanceof` and casting).

All of which probably means you want to do something else.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might find the idea of [Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) useful:

For example:

*Interface*

```
public interface TestWithGenerics<T> {

    public T getInstance();
}
```

*Implementation*

```
public class TestImplementation implements TestWithGenerics<TestImplementation> {

    @Override
    public TestImplementation getInstance() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

However, as the comments said, this all feels a bit funny. I find singletons to be a code smell. But I'm not sure what your requirements are, and I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As both the classes implement the interface `MyInterface` hence object of each class will be of type `MyInterface`.

```
public interface MyInterface{
    public MyInterface getInstance();
   // ....other methods
}

public class Class1 implements MyInterface{
     @override
     public MyInterface getInstance(){
          return this;
    }
    //... other code
}

public class Class2 implements MyInterface{
     @override
     public MyInterface getInstance(){
          return this;
    }
    //... other code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

awesome :-)
finally I implemented the solution from “T.J. Crowder”. It works fine. Many many thanks to all of you. You gave me very interested hints on my road to create “better” code……